# Help to get started with Apache Lucene in Java

Tags: java, gwt, lucene

I am using hibernate and java. I want to search data from a database and from some sites it advice to use Lucene. Can someone explain how to get started with this or point to a good tutorial!!

Does it works with database as well??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browse to [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) which should do everything you thought of (and all which you didn't, yet)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Hibernate Search is built on top of Lucene. You may also want to check up Solr - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/, an easy entry point to Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

An [official get started guide](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/gettingstarted.html) is always helpful, for any project. Also, check [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) if you want full text searching specific to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

here:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple tutorial [Lucene tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/) and if you want to go deep I advise you to read [Lucene in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394281)

Comment: excellent, exactly what I would have pointed out. I did the Lucene Tutorial myself to get started roughly a jear ago and it definitly helped a lot. Further Lucene in Action is a great book, I can very much recommend it. Furthermore some reading on information retrievel (IR) might be helpfull to understand the basic concepts: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html Reading the first 6 chapters will give you quite a solid theoretical foundation